# Como construir uma query com Web2py quantificando a diferença entre dias

Tags: python, web2py

Estou utilizando [Web2py](http://web2py.com/) (Python), fazendo a query usando a [DAL](http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/06/the-database-abstraction-layer)
Gostaria de saber se é possível pegar a diferença em dias, algo próximo a isso

**Exemplo**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python   
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

  resultado = db(
    (db.base_suporte.dt_solicitacao - db.base_suporte.dt_fechamento) >5
  ).select(db.base_suporte.dt_solicitacao)
```

por curiosidade o retorno dessa query é

```
SELECT  base_suporte.dt_solicitacao FROM base_suporte WHERE (
    (base_suporte.dt_solicitacao - base_suporte.dt_fechamento) > 5.0);
```

Eu sei que como fazer isso utilizando comandos próprios de cada base usando **db.executesql()**, mas gostaria de uma solução usando o mecanismo da DAL para que seja possível manter a compatibilidade com outros bancos

Estou usando como solução alternativa o processamento individual dos registros.

Comment: brother, checa isso: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1907088/how-can-i-make-between-query-with-web2py-dal

Comment: Fala ae @SamuelDiogo, between pega registro entre uma data é outra, isso ajudaria, mas preciso fazer a diferença de duas datas, X e Y e verificar se e maior que 5 dias

Answer (score 2):

Isvaldo, acho que o que você quer se resume ao seguinte:

```
resultado = db(
        (db.base_suporte.dt_solicitacao - db.base_suporte.dt_fechamento) >5
      ).select(db.base_suporte.dt_solicitacao, db.base_suporte.dt_fechamento)

delta = db.base_suporte.dt_fechamento - db.base_suporte.dt_solicitacao
print delta.days
```

O retorno de qualquer field do tipo `datetime` é um objeto `datetime` do python e a subtração de dois objetos deste tipo, retorna um `timedelta` equivalente a subtração de duas datas e que possui o atributo `days`, correspondente ao `int` da diferença.

Comment: Ops, acho que você se confundiu um pouco, estamos falando da classe DAL.
[DAL DOC](http://web2py.readthedocs.org/en/R-2.9.12/_modules/gluon/dal/objects.html)

Comment: @IsvaldoFernandes, não me confundi não cara. Levando em consideração que `db` é uma instância de `DAL` e que você definiu a sua tabela `base_suporte` de uma forma semelhante a...
`db.define_table('base_suporte', Field('dt_fechamento', 'datetime'), Field('dt_solicitacao', 'datetime'))`
A minha resposta se aplica e te mostrei como retornar a diferença entre os dois em dias O.o. Tem alguma parte da sua pergunta que eu interpretei mal?